# java - loading library from java library path

Tags: java

I am dependent on a library `src/main/resources/libs64/thelib.dll` which I need to load at runtime

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", 
                    Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"),
                      "src", "main", "resources", "libs64").toAbsolutePath().toString())
```

When I run the spring boot app

```
mvn package
java -jar springapp.jar
```

I tells me

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no src/main/resources/libs64/thelib in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
```

When I set the library path `src/main/resources/libs64` in Eclipse it works and the `java.library.path` prints out to the same as

```
Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"),
                          "src", "main", "resources", "libs64").toAbsolutePath().toString())
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

`src/main/resources/libs64` is the path to the library in your Eclipse project. On a system where your Eclipse workspace is not present this will never work.

When you package your app into a Jar the library (as a resource) will be copied into that jar, somewhere below the path `libs64`.

AFAIK Java can't load libraries which reside inside of a zip/jar file. Therefore you have to extract to e.g. to the temp directory and then load it from there. Or alternatively you don't pack the library into the Jar file and just deploy it next to the JAR file. Then you can load it directly from the install location of your JAR file.

Comment: I tried again with loading it from a location outside the jar via `System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:\\Username\\libs64");` and triple checked that the folder location is correct but it still gives the same error as above

Comment: BTW. Why do you set the Library path. Just load the DLL directly you already know the exact path: `System.load("C:\\Username\\libs64\\thelib.dll");`. This way it makes less problems.

Comment: Because a java library on which I am depending is loading the .dll libraries. I just need to provide the correct `java.library.path`

Comment: That does not matter. You can load the dll in your code before the java-library code tries to load it. Java loads libraries only once (identified by the library name). If it has been loaded successfully further loading attempts will be ignored (no exception).

Comment: In the end only `-Djava.library.path` worked. I debugged the `System.loadLibrary()` function and I see that it doesnt re-initialize the user path (from which it reads the libraries) once the system path (path of the jdk) is already set. So I once the jvm is running it seems there is no way to alter the java.library.path!